# JQuery fade loop too slow

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have 7 buttons (all of full opacity to begin with), when the mouse enters one button I want all buttons apart from the button that's being hovered over to fade to 0.4. Only problem is is that it appears that the fadeTo effect (in the following loop I've coded) is working sequentially, so I'm left with a sluggish fade effect, not very responsive at all.

```
    $('.button').mouseenter(function (event) {
        $('#' + $(event.target).attr('id')).fadeTo(200, 1);
        $('.button').each(function (i, obj) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') != $(event.target).attr('id'))
                $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.4);
        });
    });
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this another way??

Comment: and your html ? or even better a working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a much simpler way of doing it:

```
$('.button').mouseenter(function (event) {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 1);
    $('.button').not(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 0.4);        
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FjSLp/4/)

To fade in all the buttons when you arent hovering over any of then surround the buttons in a div with the id `buttonContainer` which has no padding and this code should work:

```
$('#buttonContainer').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $('.button').stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

[JSFiddle Example with mouseleave](http://jsfiddle.net/FjSLp/7/)

Comment: Richard, if you look on your JSFiddle example and hover right across all of the 'buttons' from left to right, you'll notice a slower fade effect, that's the problem I'm having here. It's not quite right - it's delayed. Whereas I had previously had a mouseenter (to fade in only one button) and on mouseleave faded out again only one button - a lot more responsive. I think I'm gonna have to pick here between fading all in/out and having a slower effect or goin back to handling only one button at a time on mouseenter/mouseleave.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty I've added the call to `.stop()` now. Does this do what you want?

Comment: haha spot on mate!! I need to learn a lot more about JQuery I think, the code you've written there for me is ten times as concise as what I have, I had at least 4 times the amount of code. Thanks again.

Comment: $('.button').mouseleave(function(){$('.button').stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 1);
});

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard, appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $button = $('button');
$button.mouseenter(function (event) {
    $button.not($(this)).fadeTo(200, 0.4);
});
```

See example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3ZtAC/

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot mate, exactly what I was after.

Comment: This doesn't fadeIn the hovered one.

Comment: Richard, I made a small edit to get it working - var $button = $('.button');

Comment: @RichardD I read the question itself, not the code he tried to do, so I answered to «I want all buttons apart from the button that's being hovered over to fade to 0.4» :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this without a loop using the :not selector
Hopefully it will be faster this way.

```
$('.button').mouseenter(function (event) {
    $('#' + $(event.target).attr('id')).fadeTo(200, 1);
    $('.button:not(#'+$(event.target).attr('id')+')').fadeTo(200, 0.4);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<p class="button" id="btn1">button 1</p>
<p class="button" id="btn2">button 2</p>
<p class="button" id="btn3">button 3</p>
<p class="button" id="btn4">button 4</p>
<p class="button" id="btn5">button 5</p>
<p class="button" id="btn6">button 6</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.button').mouseenter(function (event) {
  // mark that this is not inactive anymore
  $(this).stop(true, true).removeClass('inactive').fadeTo(100, 1);
  // any inactive elements and current element will not be affected, improve performance
  $('.button:not(.inactive)').not(this).stop(true, true).addClass('inactive').fadeTo(100, 0.4);
});
```

SAMPLE http://jsfiddle.net/euKkS/